# Converting a multi-band 16-bit tiff image to an 8-bit tiff image

Tags: c#, arrays, image-processing, tiff, gdal

I got some pixel data from 16-bit(range 0-65535) tif image as an integer array. I got the value using gdal readraster. How do I convert them to 8-bit(0-225) and convert it (the array) to 8-bit tif image ?

Here is some of my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OSGeo.GDAL;
using OSGeo.OSR;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Gdal.AllRegister();
            Dataset data1;
            int xsize, ysize;
            int bandsize;

            data1 = Gdal.Open("F:\\po_1473547_bgrn_0000000.tif", Access.GA_ReadOnly);

            bandsize = data1.RasterCount;

            xsize = data1.RasterXSize; //cols
            ysize = data1.RasterYSize; //rows

            Console.WriteLine("cols : "+xsize+", rows : "+ysize);

            Band[] bands = new Band[bandsize];
            for (int i = 0; i < bandsize; i++) {
                bands[i] = data1.GetRasterBand(i+1);
            }


            int[,,] pixel = new int[bandsize,xsize,ysize]; 
            int[] pixtemp = new int[xsize * ysize];


            for (int i = 0; i < bandsize; i++)
            {
                bands[i].ReadRaster(0, 0, xsize, ysize, pixtemp, xsize, ysize, 0, 0);

                for (int j = 0; j < xsize; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < ysize; k++)
                    {
                        pixel[i,j,k] = pixtemp[j + k * xsize];
                    }
                }
            }


            Console.WriteLine("");

            for (int i = 0; i < bandsize; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("some pixel from band " + (i+1));
                for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(" " + pixel[i,100,j]);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was searching Google on how to do that but I only found how to do that if the data type is a byte. Someone please give me a hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about GEO Tiff format, but to convert a regular 16 bit tiff image file to an 8 bit one, you need to scale the 16 bit channel values to 8 bits. The example below shows how this can be achieved for gray scale images.

```
public static class TiffConverter
{
    private static IEnumerable<BitmapSource> Load16BitTiff(Stream source)
    {
        var decoder = new TiffBitmapDecoder(source, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
        for (int i = 0; i < decoder.Frames.Count; i++)
            // return all frames that are present in the input.
            yield return decoder.Frames[i];
    }

    private static BitmapSource NormalizeTiffTo8BitImage(BitmapSource source)
    {
        // allocate buffer & copy image bytes.
        var rawStride = source.PixelWidth * source.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8;
        var rawImage = new byte[rawStride * source.PixelHeight];
        source.CopyPixels(rawImage, rawStride, 0);

        // get both max values of first & second byte of pixel as scaling bounds.
        var max1 = 0; 
        int max2 = 1; 
        for (int i = 0; i < rawImage.Length; i++)
        {
            if ((i & 1) == 0)
            {
                if (rawImage[i] > max1)
                    max1 = rawImage[i];
            }
            else if (rawImage[i] > max2)
                max2 = rawImage[i];
        }

        // determine normalization factors.
        var normFactor = max2 == 0 ? 0.0d : 128.0d / max2;
        var factor = max1 > 0 ? 255.0d / max1 : 0.0d;
        max2 = Math.Max(max2, 1);

        // normalize each pixel to output buffer.
        var buffer8Bit = new byte[rawImage.Length / 2];
        for (int src = 0, dst = 0; src < rawImage.Length; dst++)
        {
            int value16 = rawImage[src++];
            double value8 = ((value16 * factor) / max2) - normFactor;

            if (rawImage[src] > 0)
            {
                int b = rawImage[src] << 8;
                value8 = ((value16 + b) / max2) - normFactor;
            }
            buffer8Bit[dst] = (byte)Math.Min(255, Math.Max(value8, 0));
            src++;
        }

        // return new bitmap source.
        return BitmapSource.Create(
            source.PixelWidth, source.PixelHeight,
            source.DpiX, source.DpiY, 
            PixelFormats.Gray8, BitmapPalettes.Gray256,
            buffer8Bit, rawStride / 2);
    }

    private static void SaveTo(IEnumerable<BitmapSource> src, string fileName)
    {
        using (var stream = File.Create(fileName))
        {
            var encoder = new TiffBitmapEncoder();
            foreach (var bms in src)
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bms));
            encoder.Save(stream);
        }
    }

    public static void Convert(string inputFileName, string outputFileName)
    {
        using (var inputStream = File.OpenRead(inputFileName))
            SaveTo(Load16BitTiff(inputStream).Select(NormalizeTiffTo8BitImage), outputFileName);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
TiffConverter.Convert(@"c:\temp\16bit.tif", @"c:\temp\8bit.tif");
```

Comment: thank you very much :D, it works for 1band image, but when i use 4band image, the image got broke, which part of the code i must modify to process 4band image?

Comment: @SatriaLoka I don't know for sure, but assuming that these "bands" are present as separate frames in the decoder, this could be accommodated by simple decoding, normalizing them and adding them one by one to the output image as a converted frame. I have edited my answer to do just that.

Comment: i have separate those bands in an array, but the data type is int, can i build bitmapsource from int ? i'm afraid it will be a chaotic image if i'm not using the byte data type because ur code using byte data type

Comment: Can't you use the `TiffBitmapDecoder` as in the answer above, using `TiffConverter.Convert(@"F:\po_1473547_bgrn_0000000.tif", @"F:\new_8bit.tif");` ?

Comment: i did, the output was unexpected, it was the same as previous code, when i checked the "decoder.Frames.Count" the value is only 1 ? what i've missing here?

Comment: Ok, so that means that we know now that "bands" are not present as separate frames in the `TiffBitmapDecoder`. So, taking part of your code as the input, we would need to create a second `NormalizeTiffTo8BitImage` method where we take the `pixtemp` array as input. I don't have the time to look into that right now, but I will come back to this. In the mean time, could you provide an online link to an example/test picture as part of your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74682/discussion-between-satria-loka-and-alex).

Answer (score 0):

Interpolate pixels from 16 bit to 8 bit, some resampling methods could perform.

[Linear Interpolation](https://wiki.hexagongeospatial.com//index.php?title=File%3ARectification_linear_interpolation_diagram.png) may help.

```
//Convert tiff from 16-bit to 8-bit
byte[,,] ConvertBytes(int[,,] pixel, bandsize, xsize, ysize)
{
    byte[,,] trgPixel = new byte[bandsize,xsize,ysize];

    for (int i = 0; i < bandsize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < xsize; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < ysize; k++)
            {
                //Linear Interpolation
                trgPixel[i,j,k] = (byte)((65535-pixel[i,j,k])/65536.0*256);
            }
        }
    }

    return trgPixel;
}

//Save 8-bit tiff to file
void SaveBytesToTiff(string destPath, byte[,,] pixel, bandsize, xsize, ysize)
{
    string fileformat = "GTiff";
    Driver dr = Gdal.getDriverByName(fileformat);
    Dataset newDs = dr.Create(destPath, xsize, ysize, bandsize, DateType.GDT_Byte, null);

    for(int i=0; i< bandsize;i++)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[xsize * ysize];
        for (int j = 0; j < xsize; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < ysize; k++)
            {
                buffer[j+k*xsize] = pixel[i,j,k];
            }
        }
        newDs.WriteRaster(0, 0, xsize, ysize, buffer, xsize, ysize, i+1, null, 0, 0, 0);
        newDs.FlushCache();      
    }

    newDs.Dispose();            
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Is there something confusing? I thought it clear.

Comment: I didn't say that it was confusing. It's just that answers with only code are low quality. So please [edit] to explain basically what your code does and why you think it answers the question. I also suggest you read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer